# Expression for all points on a line segment from point $x$ to $y$

Tags: functional-analysis

Wikipedia gives the following definition for a convex set:

> Let $S$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. $C \subseteq S$ is called a *convex set* if and only if for all $x, y \in C$ and $t \in [0, 1]$, then $(1 - t)x + ty \in C$.

In other literature, I've found that they also express all the points on a line segment starting from point $x$ to $y$ by the one given in Wikipedia: $(1 - t)x + ty$. To convince myself that this correctly expresses all the points on a line segment, I played with it and got $x + t(y - x)$ which is a lot more intuitive: start from $x$ and vary the displacement $y - x$ by $t$.

What is the motivation behind expressing it the former way?

Comment: Formally we have $x + t(y-x) = (1-t)x + ty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *motivation* lies in the definition of a convex combination. For $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ a **convex combination** is of the form
$$\alpha_1x_1+\ldots+\alpha_nx_n,$$
where the $\alpha_i\geq0$ and $\alpha_1+\ldots+\alpha_n=1$.

Now note that when $t\in[0,1]$, then also $(1-t)\in[0,1]$, such that 
$$(1-t)x+ty$$
is indeed a convex combination.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just a matter of taste, but let me answer with a picture.

[image]